# Crash at self.view presentviewcontroller:UIImagePickerController in iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6

When i try to call the photo Album from xcode 4.5 ,app crashes .
Note : I  set the app orientation to landscape mode.

```
UIImagePickerController *picker=nil;
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
{
    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    picker.allowsEditing = NO;
    picker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:
            UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum];

}

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone ) {
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: That code is in a view controller?

Comment: What does the exception/error/crash look like?

Comment: Can you be more specific? How can u be sure that the first statement is true when the second statement is reached? When you're calling presentViewController::: how can you be sure that picker is not nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One error in your logic is that if `isSourceTypeAvailable` returns NO on an iPhone you will attempt to present a controller that's `nil`.